# Find indexes of multiple values which are matching in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

so I have two dropdown values which are in array format .
`dropdownArray1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `dropdownarray2= [A,B,C,D,E,F]`.
If I select `[2,4,6]` from the `dropdownArray1` then the values corresponding to the index from the `dropdownarray2` should be selected. i.e., expected answer is `[B,D,F]`.

Comment: could you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: @hgb123 i am not getting the right solution to try actually. hence have posted the question. it would be great if you can provide me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` on `arr1`, When ever you find item in selections, then push same indexed item from `arr2`

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
const arr2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];

const sel = [2,4,6];

const res = arr1.reduce((acc, cur, i) => 
              (sel.includes(cur) && acc.push(arr2[i]), acc), []);

console.log(res)
```

Alternatively, use `filter` on `arr2`

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
const arr2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];

const sel = [2,4,6];

const res = arr2.filter((_, i) => sel.includes(arr1[i]));

console.log(res)
```